# DNS resolution in LXC container

Tags: networking, dns, lxc

I'm using srsLTE-emane (https://github.com/adjacentlink/srsLTE-emane), an open source software that emulates LTE Network, on Ubuntu 18.04.2, and I have a problem with DNS resolution in LXC container.

I'm running a demonstration (found on https://github.com/adjacentlink/emane-model-lte.git) made by three containers: ue-02 (the mobile phone), enb-21 (the radio base station) and epc-01 (the core network of LTE). I'm able to ping any IP address from ue-02 (for example 104.83.108.242):

```
root@ue-02:~# ping 104.83.108.242 -c 5
PING 104.83.108.242 (104.83.108.242) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 104.83.108.242: icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=96.8 ms
64 bytes from 104.83.108.242: icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=95.1 ms
64 bytes from 104.83.108.242: icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=94.5 ms
64 bytes from 104.83.108.242: icmp_seq=4 ttl=50 time=93.0 ms
64 bytes from 104.83.108.242: icmp_seq=5 ttl=50 time=91.8 ms
```

I'm not able to activate the DNS resolution (where www.repubblica.it is the internet site related to 104.83.108.242):

```
root@ue-02:~# nslookup www.repubblica.it
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

root@ue-02:~# LC_ALL=C ping www.repubblica.it
ping: www.repubblica.it: Name or service not known
```

I have read the instructions to modify the file resolv.conf, but these containers don't have this file: these are a bit different from classical LXC containers. The unique configuration file is lxc.conf.

lxc.conf:

```
lxc.uts.name=ue-02
lxc.net.0.type=veth
lxc.net.0.name=backchan0
lxc.net.0.flags=up
lxc.net.0.link=letce0
lxc.net.0.ipv4.address=10.88.1.2/24
lxc.net.0.veth.pair=aveth.3.0
lxc.net.1.type = empty
lxc.net.1.flags=up

lxc.console.path = none
lxc.tty.max = 1
lxc.pty.max = 128
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = a
lxc.mount.auto = proc sys cgroup


lxc.autodev = 1
lxc.hook.autodev = /usr/share/emane-model-lte/demo/two_ues/ue-02/lxc.hook.autodev.sh
lxc.apparmor.profile = unconfined
```

the only differences with lxc.conf of the other two containers are in the name and in the IP addresses.

I have tried to modify the file lxc.conf in /etc/dnsmasq.d-available, adding the line

`dhcp-option=option:dns-server,8.8.8.8`

and also (alternately)

`dhcp-option=option:dns-server,0.0.0.0,8.8.8.8`

but this did not work.
I have also tried to set DNS servers in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` (with line `DNS=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4`) and then restart systemd-resolved, without effects.
Note that "normal" LXC containers (created with command `sudo lxc-create`) work fine.

Output of `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf | grep hosts`:

```
andrea@andrea-Latitude-7490:~$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf | grep hosts
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

Someone could help me?

Thank you very much!!

Andrea

Comment: what version of ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.2 (added to the question).

Comment: is systemd-resolved.service up? `sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved.service`? Have you tried to set DNS servers in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and then restart systemd-resolved? Or even temporarly set nameservers directly in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: The service is up. I have tried to set DNS in `resolved.conf` with the line  `DNS=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4` and restart the service but without effects. (question updated). Note that "normal" LXC containers (created with command `sudo lxc-create`) work fine.

Comment: can you please add output from `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf | grep hosts`?

Comment: @Comar:
`andrea@andrea-Latitude-7490:~$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf | grep hosts
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname`

Comment: What about `echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf` Also please read these posts: https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/dns-for-lxc-containers/235/4 https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/set-dns-nameserver-via-lxc-command/720/2

Comment: @Comar Yes, your command works! You can post the answer! Thank you!!

Comment: unfortunately it won't work on long term, cause systemd will change it eventually, so you should rather set it through systemd-resolved and NetworkManager (switch DNS to static)

Comment: @Comar Yes, but for me is not a problem. I run the command every time I need it.